# Group by data based on one field of list

Tags: python, grouping

I have input data like this

```
input = ((1,'MCA', 'Science'),(2,'physic', 'Science'),(3,'chemsitry', 'Science'),(4,'punjabi', 'arts'),(5,'hindi', 'arts'))
```

I want to group this data by third field (Science/arts) like this

```
result = {"arts":[{"id":"4","name":"punjabi"},{"id":"5","name":"hindi"}],"Science":[{"id":"1","name":"MCA"},{"id":"2","name":"physics"},{"id":"3","name":"chemistry"}]}
```

How can I achieve this in an efficient way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend a `collections.defaultdict`. Iterate over your original data and assign new dictionaries to this `defaultdict`.

```
import collections
result = collections.defaultdict(list)
i = ((1,'MCA', 'Science'),(2,'physic', 'Science'),(3,'chemsitry', 'Science'),(4,'punjabi', 'arts'),(5,'hindi', 'arts'))
for id,name,subject in i:
    result[subject].append({'id':str(id), 'name':name})
```

You end up with the following result:

```
>>> result
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'Science': [{'name': 'MCA', 'id': '1'}, {'name': 'physic', 'id': '2'}, {'name': 'chemsitry', 'id': '3'}], 'arts': [{'name': 'punjabi', 'id': '4'}, {'name': 'hindi', 'id': '5'}]})
```

It doesn't affect the algorithm, but remember to double-check the content's spelling before putting it into the program (viz `'chemsitry'` et al.).

Comment: can you please convert like this :{"data": [{"Departcategory":"Science","DepartmentNames":[{"departmentId":1,"name": "MCA"},{"departmentId":2,"name":"physics"  }]},{"Departcategory":"Arts","DepartmentNames":[{"departmentId": 3,"name": "punjabi"},{"departmentId": 4,"name": "hindi"}]}]}

Answer (score 2):

Just iterate through the input, inserting each item into the results dictionary:

```
result = {}
for id, name, subject in input:
    if subject not in result:
         result[subject] = []
    result[subject].append({"id":str(id), "name":name})
```

Comment: You might want to avoid the name `input` (and no need for the `;`).

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I just used `input` because that's what the OP called it, but you are correct that it's not an ideal name. As for the `;` you are also correct! Had my mind in Java lately - I'll correct it now. Thanks for the catch!